# How can I update the style of an element inside a list dynamically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am making a Fast Reading exercise app with flutter. I tried run foreach loop on my list to update TextSpans opacity but it didn't work. After that, I tried to replace the element with a new TextSpan and a new opacity, element changed inside the list but it didn't render on screen. Here is my code.

```
  var textList = <TextSpan>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();            
    text.split(' ').forEach((element) {
      textList.add(TextSpan(text:element));                     
    });
  }
```

```
    Widget _textArea() {
      return FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 0.9,
          heightFactor: 0.9,
          child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: textList
                  ),
                ) 
              ));
    }
```

I need to update the opacities of each element inside `textList` every second and the update function has to start with ``ònPress```event.
I am stuck on that issue.

FULL CODE

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePeageReaderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePeageReaderWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageReaderWidgetState createState() => _HomePageReaderWidgetState();
}

class _HomePageReaderWidgetState extends State<HomePeageReaderWidget> {
  var text =
      """Gaziantep şehri Türkiye'nin güneydoğusundadır. Çok güzel bir şehirdir. Belki İstanbul ve Ankara kadar büyük değildir, ama yine de burada bir milyonun üstünde insan yaşıyor. Gaziantep'te iş alanları çok geniştir, herkes çalışıyor. Birçok fabrikalar ve atölyeler vardır. Ayrıca bir de Gaziantep Üniversitesi vardır. Üniversite şehirden biraz uzak, ama yurt da üniversitenin yanında. Bunun için ulaşım sorunu yok.Gaziantep'te yazın hava çok sıcak oluyor, insanlar evlerinden ve iş yerlerinden dışarıya çıkmıyorlar. Gece balkonlarda yatıyorlar. Kışın ise havalar sert, sokaklar ise her zaman ıslaktır.""";

  var textList = <TextSpan>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    text.split(' ').forEach((element) {      
      textList.add(TextSpan(text: element));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _controlRow() {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
                iconSize: 50,
                color: const Color(0xFFffcd05),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.pause_circle),
                iconSize: 50,
                color: const Color(0xFF91268e),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_next),
                iconSize: 50,
                color: const Color(0xFFffcd05),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    Widget _textArea() {
      return FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 0.9,
          heightFactor: 0.9,
          child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(children: textList),
              )));
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: _textArea(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: _controlRow(),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 300,
          child: ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
              // Respond to button press
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, size: 18),
            label: Text("Hızlı Egzersiz"),
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all(const Color(0xFF075098)),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to animate the text?

Comment: yes i tried to use a package for that but it also didn't work for me because i need to change current element's opacity to one and before element to a 0.7 but it doesnt matter right now because i cant even change opacity or anything inside list when i changed it also doesnt render on screen

Comment: if you need I can add full  code

Comment: you need to use some kind of animation widget, Try AnimatedOpacity or FadeTransition.

Comment: okay but I want to change those opacities inside a for loop that loops every second and it should be run on onPress event. When I did that elements opacity is changed but it didnt render on screen.

Comment: for loop with less iterations will finish in milliseconds. are you updating the state after loop finished?

Comment: I am updating the item inside list if that counts yes but if I need to reinitiate the list I didn't try that. I just put sleep inside list after I changed the element inside list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setState( )` so your changes are reflected in the client.

Dont forget that you need to keep a `StatefulWidget` so that `setState` works

**Code:**

```
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() { 
      yourOpacityValue = updatedOpacityValue; });
  },
```

Comment: I need to change opacities separately for each and every one of my elements. So if my text has 10000 words I need to set 10000 states. Maybe I can render Text elements as a separate Statefull widget, but IDK how can I change widget opacity inside the parent element if I do that.

Comment: You can change all 10000 values inside the same one setState

Comment: How can I do that separately for each Item when the 4th Item's opacity is 1, the first second, and the third Item's opacity has to be 0.7. And I don't even know how many words have that paragraph.

Comment: @kemalkaancetindag If your app has 10,000 separate stateful widgets that all need to be simultaneously changed and refreshed, you need to take a step back and re-evaluate your approach.

Comment: unfortunately you are right :(